# Solve Symbolic Function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I'm using syms variables so i can store the functions or polynomial for later calculation in script file.

The problem is when i use subs to put value of syms variable into function or polynomial,it doesn't solve the functions completely.like

```
>>syms x
>>subs(x^2-x,x,2)
ans =

6    (Complete solved)
```

but

```
>>subs(sin(x),x,2)
ans =

sin(2)    (Not completely solved)
```

i want ans like

```
>>sin(2)

ans =

0.9093
```

What should i use?? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I Used VPA(Variable-precision arithmetic) function to make it work.now if

```
>>vpa(subs(sin(x),x,2),5)
ans(x) =

0.9093
```